# How can I add some caption to parbox

Tags: captions, framed, border

I am using

```
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        text
    }%
}
```

For a box around text like this:
[image]

How can I add some caption and use this caption as reference in text?

Somethink like this:

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionbox{}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356405/alignment-in-captionbox-and-parbox

Comment: You want to be able to put a custom caption type there with custom label?

Comment: Skillmon: yes, right,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `adjustbox` for this. Use either the `float` or `nofloat` key. You need to define a new float type in either case, e.g. using `newfloat` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for example text only
\usepackage{hyperref}% for hyperlinked references

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=loc,
listname={List of cars},
name=Car,
placement=pbth,
within=section,
%chapterlistsgaps=off,
]{car}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\lipsum

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule, fbox, captionbelow={ferrari}, label={car:ferrari}, nofloat=car}
Test
\end{adjustbox}

See my new car~\ref{car:ferrari}.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]